# A required class was missing while executing org.apache.axis2:axis-wsdl2code-maven-plugin:1.3

Tags: maven, java-8, maven-3, pom.xml

I am trying to upgrade my project running in 1.5 to 1.8(jdk), and I am using Maven 3.0.4 in conjunction. While trying to execute command "mvn build" I get the error "The required class was missing while executing org.apache.axis2:axis2-wsdl2code-maven-plugin:1.3:wsdl2code: org/apache/neethi/policy".

I have tried installing fresh jars and pom files, added them to the build path, also added it to POM dependencies. I even added axis2-codegen jar as suggested in some answer in this site. I've even tried "mvn -U clean install", also as suggested in one the answers. But so far nothing seems to work. I am fairly new to Maven, so any help will be appreciated.

P.S.: I cannot post any actual code or snapshots of the errors as it is a corporate project. I have tried to put up as much data as possible without breaching my NDA.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you getting a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` in your stacktrace? If you do not see a stacktrace, run your maven command with a `mvn build -e`.

Comment: I have a ClassNotFoundException for org.apache.neethi.Policy; but I also have PluginContainerException, PluginExecutionException and LifecycleExecutionException due to the wsdl2code-maven-plugin

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not get a compile error, I am assuming there should be conflicting transient dependencies.

Try executing,

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dincludes=org.apache.axis2
```

If you have multiple versions of the same dependency, have the unintended versions excluded in your pom file.

Note: You can do this operation in your IDE too. "IntelliJ Idea", has a really nice interface for this operation.